# A ring with a left cancellable element and a right identity always has an identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a ring with $a, e \in R$ such that $a$ is not a left zero-divisor and $be=b, \forall b \in R$. Prove that $R$ has an identity.

**My attempt** Let, $aeb = ab \Rightarrow aeb - ab = 0 \Rightarrow a(eb - b) = 0$, since $a \neq LZD$, $eb - b = 0 \Rightarrow eb = b$. Hence, $e$ is the identity element of $R$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct !

Comment: Could be shorter using left cancellation: $\,aeb=ab\Rightarrow eb=b$ since $a isn't a l.z.d.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tries to do it rigorously.

Comment: Your attempt looks correct to me. :) I would just like to add that since the ring has a left cancellable element, so it has an element a that is not a left zero divisor. If you don't state this result, then one might wonder how you assumed the existence of a zero divisor in a ring that isn't mentioned to be an integral domain.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mention that.